# How do I use user AD account when using SecretClient in node/TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure-keyvault

I am trying to use the Azure Key Vault Secret client library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/keyvault-secrets) and I'm running into problems with authentication. The examples all use a service principal, but I am trying to also allow access using an AD user. This could be by getting the user from the running context or via username/password. Is this possible using this library? If not, do I need to use a different library, or do I need to make the REST calls directly?

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you want to use the username and password to get Azure Key Vault secret. We can use `UsernamePasswordCredential` in the SDK`@azure/identity` to implement it. The detailed steps are as below.

1. Register Azure AD application
   [image]
   [image]
2. Configure Azure AD application

   - Make it as public client
     [image]
   - Configure API permissions
     [image]
3. Sample

   a. install SDK

   ```
   npm install @azure/keyvault-secrets
   npm install @azure/identity
   npm install dotenv
   ```

   b. create `.env`file

   ```
   AZURE_TENANT_ID=<your tenant id>
   AZURE_CLIENT_ID=<your appid>
   AZURE_USERNAME=<your AzureAD user account>
   AZURE_PASSWORD=<your AzureAD account password>
   ```

   c. code

   ```
   var keyvault = require('@azure/keyvault-secrets')
   var azure = require('@azure/identity')
   const dotenv = require('dotenv');
   dotenv.config();

   async function main() {
    const creds = new  azure.UsernamePasswordCredential(process.env.AZURE_TENANT_ID,process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_ID,process.env.AZURE_USERNAME,process.env.AZURE_PASSWORD)
             const client = new keyvault.SecretClient('<your key vault url>',creds)
             const secret = await client1.getSecret('<your secret name>')
             console.log(secret)
   }

   main()
     .then(() => {
       console.log("Successfully executed sample.");
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err.message);
     });
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for how to do this with an AD User, not service principal/app registration

Comment: @ErickT What do you mean "do this with an AD User"?

Comment: With an active directory user, like you’d use with the portal. A user has an UsedId and an ObjectId, but not a ClientId like an App Registration/Service Principal

Comment: @ErickT When we login Azure portal, the login url will also contain the client id of AD application. But it is created by Microsoft and we do not need to do these.  Because when we access the resource protected by Azure AD, we must  register Azure AD application, configure permissions for the application and provide client id when we get access token. For more details,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview